# C++ Boost.ASIO: passing accepted TCP connection from one opened socket to another using Windows APIs ( while works with Linux APIs)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, connection, boost-asio

I was trying to learn how to re assign accepted connection using Boost.ASIO and Windows API's. found [this code sample](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5157) added to it includes and use of namespaces so now it is compilable - just copy and paste and here you go... "The parameter is incorrect" exception at the same place code poster had it=( So here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Windows.h"
#endif

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

int main(){
int m_nPort = 12345;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_nPort));

cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;

tcp::socket socket(io_service);
acceptor.accept(socket);
cout << "connection accepted" << endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
WSAPROTOCOL_INFO pi;
WSADuplicateSocket(socket.native(), GetCurrentProcessId(), &pi);
SOCKET socketDup = WSASocket(pi.iAddressFamily/*AF_INET*/, pi.iSocketType/*SOCK_STREAM*/,
                             pi.iProtocol/*IPPROTO_TCP*/, &pi, 0, 0);
char sText[] = "I can use my duplicated socket via WinApi!\r\n";
int nRet = send(socketDup, sText, strlen(sText), 0);
#else
//linux
 int socketDup = dup(socket.native()); // tested on Linux, works!
#endif

try
{
    tcp::socket s(io_service);
    s.assign(tcp::v4(), socketDup); //this throws exception under Windows
    //I can't use my socket via boost lib
    s.send(boost::asio::buffer("Not work\r\n"));
    cout << "We do not get here!=(" << endl;
}
catch(exception &e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl; //"The parameter is incorrect" exception
}
cin.get();
}
```

In general [code follows this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966323/boostasio-and-socket-ownership/2968774#2968774) and I actually do not see what is wrong neither how to fix it.

And it follows way how we would pass accepted TCP connection from one process to another ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312773/c-application-is-it-possible-to-pass-accepted-tcp-connection-from-one-process/5312969#5312969))

May be [this "Socket inheritance on different Windows platforms" example could help](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;150523) but I do not see how.

Can any one please help me to find any possible workaround that problem?

---

**Update:**
Just tested code on Linux - works perfectly, no errors.

So what is it with windows version?

Comment: [offtopic] .. for a moment I was wondering what Boost was doing in the spook busines (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Security_Intelligence_Organisation) instead of the compiler business (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try using the code snippet attached to the `WSASocket` documentation:</strike>

```
socketDup = WSASocket(FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, FROM_PROTOCOL_INFO, &pi, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
```

---

Ok, I traced through the Boost code, and it fails trying to associate the socket with the I/O completion port.  That's because the socket is already associated to a completion port.

[The MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363862.aspx) say:

> It is best not to share a file handle associated with an I/O completion port by using either handle inheritance or a call to the DuplicateHandle function. Operations performed with such duplicate handles generate completion notifications. Careful consideration is advised.

Knowing that IOCP is related to the problem, I set (before including any boost headers)

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP 1
```

and everything works fine.

local output:

```
Waiting for connection...
connection accepted
We do not get here!=(
```

remote output:

```
I can use my duplicated socket via WinApi!
Not work
```

Comment: Hm... Tried - seems to be the same error..=( Have you tried? Does it work on your machine?

Comment: @Blender: I don't have boost installed on my work machine.  I can try compiling your file when I get home.

Comment: I't would be grate! Waiting for your help.

Comment: small notice for nubs like me - `#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP 1` has to be set **before** `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`

Comment: @Blender: correct.  I guess it wouldn't hurt me to include that important detail.