# Boost::Asio Serial Read/Write open: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost-asio

I've really basic knowledge on C++ and I'm trying to read/write Serial Port by using Visual Studio. I'm trying to use **Boost::Asio** but I'm always getting similar errors. While I'm trying to run the code below I'm getting "**Error: open: The parameter is incorrect**".

To make sure serial port and my device is working correctly, I used another application. I'm able to read/write without no problem. After my test I closed my application to not to cause any problem.

**UPDATE:** By using Virtual Serial Port Emulator(VSPE) I created pair of ports(COM1 and COM2). I used COM1 in C++ and COM2 in RealTerm. By this I successfully read/write data with my code without any problem. But while I'm trying to access COM6, I still get same error. An FPGA connected to that port and I also tested FPGA with RealTerm which is able to read/write, means working as I expected. So, It's look like my problem is accessing to the COM6 port. Looking for your advice.

I'm open to any kind of suggestion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleSerial.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {

        SimpleSerial serial("COM6", 115200);

        serial.writeString("Hello world\n");

        cout << serial.readLine() << endl;

    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error & e)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I found this SimpleSerial Class online and tried to make basic application.

```
class SimpleSerial
{
public:
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * \param port device name, example "/dev/ttyUSB0" or "COM4"
     * \param baud_rate communication speed, example 9600 or 115200
     * \throws boost::system::system_error if cannot open the
     * serial device
     */
    SimpleSerial(std::string port, unsigned int baud_rate)
        : io(), serial(io, port)
    {
        serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
    }

    /**
     * Write a string to the serial device.
     * \param s string to write
     * \throws boost::system::system_error on failure
     */
    void writeString(std::string s)
    {
        boost::asio::write(serial, boost::asio::buffer(s.c_str(), s.size()));
    }

    /**
     * Blocks until a line is received from the serial device.
     * Eventual '\n' or '\r\n' characters at the end of the string are removed.
     * \return a string containing the received line
     * \throws boost::system::system_error on failure
     */
    std::string readLine()
    {
        //Reading data char by char, code is optimized for simplicity, not speed
        using namespace boost;
        char c;
        std::string result;
        for (;;)
        {
            asio::read(serial, asio::buffer(&c, 1));
            switch (c)
            {
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\n':
                return result;
            default:
                result += c;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port serial;
};
```

Comment: You might want to try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329413/4253931

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing

```
dcb.BaudRate = 0;
```

to

```
dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
```

in include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_serial_port_service.ipp i.e. `boost::system::error_code win_iocp_serial_port_service::open`, which is a work around for a known issue, with open merge requests in boost::asio , see 
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/issues/280 and 
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/pull/273 .

You can still use other baud settings, by using the portable options after opening, but windows won't accept 0 in the hope of the intention "use the baud used before", as the authors hoped.

Hopefully it will be changed and I will post the boost version in this post, when it will work without hot patching boost implementation again.